# Gembird DVI-D to VGA adapter cable screen turning on and off randomly

Tags: display, display-adapter

I am using a DVI-D to VGA adapter cable but my screen just randomly turns on and off showing - I think -  DVI-D in the right corner. It would happen randomly but happens more with certain thing, if I watch YouTube it will only happen about 2 times a day but if I play games it will happen about 1 once every 10 min or more.

Comment: This would be an active converter. It may not get enough power. Does it have a connector (often Mini/Micro-USB) to supply more power?

Comment: No it does not, is there some way for me to check if it's not getting enough power, sorry I don't know crap about computers lol

Answer (score 0):

Intermittent signal loss is a relatively clear sign of insufficient power.

Converting DVI to VGA requires an active converter. If there is no external power supply, the converter must rely in the +5 Volt pin that is present on the DVI port. Unfortunately, there doesn’t appear to be any requirements about the current that this pin supplies. It may be very little.

There are multiple options on how to go forward:

- Newer display that does not require signal conversion
- Different VGA-to-DVI adapter, preferably with external power supply (typically via USB)
- If compatible<sup>1</sup>, a DVI-A to VGA adapter (passive)

1: DVI-A ports are relatively easy to identify. If one end of the connector looks like the following image (picture [taken from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#/media/File:Computer_DVI_connector.jpg)), with 4 slots, it’s DVI-A:

[image: side of DVI port]

---

In case I misunderstood and it’s actually VGA (PC) → DVI (Monitor), the answer still applies. VGA supplies power, it’s not a lot, active adapter required etc.. However, I am not aware of displays that accept DVI-A, so the last option is out.